# Completion in Updating Location Manager

Tags: swift, swift2, ios9, cllocationmanager

I'm having an issue with the Update Location Manager.

So this is what i want to do. When the user goes into the view, it asks for location permision, when the user refuses i have set up a code that i will not post here cause it works. But if he accepts i run a function that i get the latitude and longitude of his. And then i want to run a function in which i do a query to an API. The following code is what I made

```
var tolat: Double = 0.0
var tolon: Double = 0.0
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters

            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        }


        getData() { result in
            switch result {
            case .Success: self.eventsTable.reloadData()
            case .Failure(let error): break
            }
        }



}


 func getData(completion: Resulty<Void> -> Void) {
        print("the lat \(tolat) and the lon \(tolon)")
        completion(.Success())
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate

    tolat = locValue.latitude
    tolon = locValue.longitude

    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()




}
```

and after the end of the view

```
enum Resulty<T> {
    case Success(T)
    case Failure(NSError)
}
```

So it prints 0.0 the latitude and longitude. How can i make the `func getData` run when the Location Latitude and Longitude actually has data???